# Why I cannot run `apt update` inside a fresh ubuntu:22.04?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I currently don't manage to run `apt update` inside a fresh `ubuntu:22.04` (codename `jammy`).

### Protocol

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61

$ docker run --init --rm -it ubuntu:22.04
root@123456789:/# apt update
```

#### Observed

```sh
$ docker run --init --rm -it ubuntu:22.04
root@6444bf2cb8b4:/# apt update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]            
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [90.7 kB] 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [90.7 kB]             
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]       
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]           
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]             
Fetched 20.2 MB in 1s (17.6 MB/s)                                                           
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
root@6444bf2cb8b4:/#
```

### Expected

`apt update` pass like on a `ubuntu:20.04` base image...

note: same issue with `apt-get install` ...

ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu

Comment: You need to install latest `docker`. In my case installing version `20.10.14` helped. It did not work with `20.10.8`

Comment: Nice, this helped me. Update docker-ce works for me.

Comment: This could be moved to AskUbuntu or SuperUser.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Seems this is related to the use of the syscall `clone3` by `Glibc >= 2.34`...

So you need `Docker >= 20.10.9` to fix it.

ref: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/42681
ref: https://pascalroeleven.nl/2021/09/09/ubuntu-21-10-and-fedora-35-in-docker/

Comment: `v20.10.9` isn't working, newer version fixed the problem

Comment: Worked here with version 20.10.22. Had to reinstall Docker (updating with `apt get update` was not detecting updates). Following https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-docker-engine helped. Restart in the end and it should work.

Answer (score 25):

I ran into the same issue. Here is my tactical work-around.

### For context ...

I am working inside a Gitpod instance.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
$ docker pull ubuntu:22.04
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:22.04 /bin/bash

root@2fcf92fb7c84:/# apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [90.7 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
Fetched 20.2 MB in 2s (11.1 MB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

### Quick nano install ...

Despite the error message above, the update was sufficient to install `nano`. I ignore the misleading error message at the end of the `nano` install.

```
root@3958950e9c57:/# apt install nano
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
  :
E: Problem executing scripts DPkg::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

### My fix ...

I use nano to edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean`, commenting out the second line (`APT::...`). I subsequently ran into a similar error message with line 1 (`DPkg::...`); so, it too gets commented out.

It might be okay to just remove `docker-clean` all together; but for now, I have left one line in place.

*Both '//' and '#' can be used to comment out lines.*

```
root@3958950e9c57:/# nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean

  .. nano session not shown ..

root@3958950e9c57:/# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean
# DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
# APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
```

### The results ...

The confusing message resulting from the now commented-out lines is gone.

```
root@beab61fbde20:/# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
```

### Required Improvement ...

A better solution would be to repair the line that I have commented out. I was not able to find the right edits; so, just left the line commented out.

### In Docker ...

I use `sed` in lieu of `nano`.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
USER root

RUN sed -i -e 's/^APT/# APT/' -e 's/^DPkg/# DPkg/' \
      /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean
```

Then, tag an adjusted Ubuntu image for local use.

```
docker build -t fixed-ubuntu:22.04 -f Dockerfile .
```

Comment: I ran into this with docker v20.10.17 build 100c70180f. I'm on macos 12.4. This answer helped me get past the issue but I'm still wondering why this is occurring.

Comment: I ran into this with the same specifications of @user1052313 but using macos 10.13.6 High Sierra. Still not able to fix it. I even tried by removing docker-clean but didn't work

Answer (score 6):

I upgraded docker engine to version 20.10.14 and it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had docker 20.10.18 (latest at time writing) which didn't work, with 20.10.14 it started to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).